# class inheritance code not working

Tags: c++, constructor

I have checked the class inheritance syntax and I'm pretty sure I don’t have a mistake ? did anything slip away from me ?

```
   class person
{
public:
int personid;
string personname;
string personadress;
person( int apersonid, string apersonname, string apersonadress )//constructor
{
    personid=apersonid;
    personname=apersonname;
    personadress=apersonadress;
}
int getpersonid()
{
    return personid;
}
string getpersonname()
{
    return personname;
}
string getpersonadress()
{
    return personadress;
}
 };

class employee: public person
 {
 public:
int commission;
employee(int _commission, int apersonid, string apersonname, string apersonaddress) : person(apersonid, apersonname, apersonaddress)
{
    commission= _commission;
}
int getcommission()
{
    return commission;
    }
 };
```

The error I'm getting is

> Error 1   error C2512: 'person' : no appropriate default constructor
>   available

Comment: different signatures on the constructors. In other languages, your inheriting class calls the constructor of the base class with the same signature implicitly. So I would suggest either writing a constructor with the same arguments or calling the base constructor explicitly. Just a guess though since I don't know what language you're using.

Comment: the language im using is c++..

Comment: [use initialization lists](http://makecleanandmake.com/2014/10/31/c-anitpatterns-the-java-constructor-and-final-vs-const/)

Comment: @RyanHaining That was a very interesting read! I'm learning c++ from a C# background so I'm obviously prone to this anti-pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem is that your base class doesn't define a default constructor (with 0 arguments). Instead you have a constructor with multiple arguments.

```
person( int apersonid, string apersonname, string apersonadress )//constructor
{
    personid=apersonid;
    personname=apersonname;
    personadress=apersonadress;
}
```

Your employee class inherits from person but it's constructor only takes one argument and does not initialize the base class using it's constructor.

```
employee( int _commission )
{
   commission= _commission;
}
```

This is an issue b/c when you create an instance of the employee, it's trying to call the person class constructor as well. Since you don't have a default constructor (again, no arguments), you will need to explicitly call the person constructor in the employee constructor.

You have two options.

First, Modify the person constructor to take no arguments

```
person()
```

If you use this method, your signature for your employee class won't have to change.

Or you can Modify the employee constructor to take all the arguments the person constructor expects:

```
class employee: public person
{
   public:
   int commission;

   employee(int _commision, int apersonid, string apersonname, string apersonadress ) : person(apersonId, apersonname, apersonadress)
   {
      commission = _commission;
   }
   int getcommission()
   {
      return commission;
   }
};
```

In the constructor, the code after the colon (:) is a call to the person constructor using the arguments specified (apersonid, apersonname, apersonadress).

The employee constructor then assigns the value of _commission since it's scope is only relevant within the employee class.

Does that make sense?

Comment: but i thought that when y inherits  x, it takes its methods. so no need to mention them in y... so if i move the arguments to y, then no need to use inheritance.
can u please tell me how will the first option can be executed ?

Comment: It does inherit the methods. And it inherits the constructor. But if you only define a constructor on employee with one parameter, how could you create an employee during construction that will have all the information a person needs to be constructed. Right now, to create an employee, you would call employee(2500). But the person class still needs an id, name, address. Where does it get that information

Comment: ugh trying to fix it but nothing is working... not sure if im asking alot...but fcan u write the fix ?

Comment: Can you edit your post and show us what you've tried?

Comment: ohh wait wait just edited it ! it worked . look at my last edit

Comment: Yes exactly! That is just what I finished updating to show but you figured it out!

Comment: If it's helped, remember to mark the answer as the solution. Also, check out Ryan's comments too on list initialization.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, if constructors are explicitly defined for a class, but they are all non-default, the compiler will not implicitly define a default constructor, leading to a situation where the class does not have a default constructor. You have defined a non default constructor in your class, this one :

```
person( int apersonid, string apersonname, string apersonadress )
```

So you need to define one default constructor yourself. E.g.

```
person() {}
```

Keep in mind, that in this case, when you construct an object of `employee` class the default constructor of `person` would be called. If that is not desired you need to call the non-default constructor of `person` in the constructor of `employee`.